# What's different between Hall and Knight "Higher Algebra" and Barnard and Child "Higher Algebra"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, book-recommendation

So I'm mainly looking for Algebra books for the purpose of Olympiads, but I also want to learn just a bit higher too for personal enjoyment. I currently have 2 in mind: the ones in the title. Since both are of the same name, and there wasn't enough info that I could find online regarding the latter, I just wanted to ask about the similarities and differences between the two and ultimately, for what I want to do, which one will be better?

Comment: In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843268/algebra-books-for-olympiad-preparation) Hall and Knight is said to be better, because of many exercises. Here at stackexchange several exercises of it have been solved, too. But you should look for more recommendations yourself.